# How to return the entire row of a Max value in a column in SQL?

Tags: mysql

Here is my table

```
Customer     Serial#     Date       PM
A            01          01/01/01   PM1
A            01          01/02/01   PM2
B            03          01/01/01   PM4
C            05          01/03/01   PM2
```

I only want the row for the max date by Customer and Serial#. So this:

```
Customer    Serial#      Date       PM
A           01           01/02/01   PM2
B           03           01/01/01   PM4
C           05           01/03/01   PM2
```

I can't exclude the PM column from the Group By function so it ends up bringing in everything...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: select Customer, Serial#, Max(Date), PM
from Table
group by Customer, Serial#, PM

Like i said, I know including the PM Column is the issue. But excluding it give me an error. Its like I need a MAX(PM) by Date or something of that nature

Comment: @Conner - Please move the comment to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the query below

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Customer, Serial#, Date, PM 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Customer, Serial# ORDER BY Date DESC) AS rn
    FROM Table 
) a
WHERE rn = 1
```